# If $f(x+y^3)=f(x)+[f(y)]^3$ and $f'(0)\ge0$, what can $f(10)$ be?

Tags: derivatives, functional-equations

A real valued function satisfies the condition: $f(x+y^3)=f(x)+[f(y)]^3$ for all real $x$, $y$.

If $f'(0)\ge0$ how to find $f(10)$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

Using the condition $f(x+y^3)=f(x)+[f(y)]^3$, we note that for any $x$, we have
$$
f'(x) = 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h^3) - f(x)}{h^3} = 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(f(x) +[f(h)]^3) - f(x)}{h^3}
=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[f(h)]^3}{h^3}
$$
We may deduce that $f(0) = 0$ and that 
$f'(x)$ does *not* depend on $x$, so that $f$ has constant slope.  In particular, for any $x$, we have $f'(x) = f'(0)$.

Since $f$ has constant slope and $f(0) = 0$, we must have $f(x) = [f'(0)]x$.  Moreover, we also have
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[f(h)]^3}{h^3} = 
\left[\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[f(h)]}{h}\right]^3 = [f'(0)]^3
$$
From which we may deduce that we either have $f'(0) = 0$ or $f'(0) = 1$.

Comment: Are you using that $f(0)=0$, so $[f(h)]^3=f(h^3)$?

Comment: @user84413 is my answer any clearer now?

Comment: Yes, thanks; I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

Let $(x,y)=(0,t)$:$$
f(0+t^3) = f(t^3) = f(0) + [f(t)]^3
$$We can use this to find $f(0)$:$$
f(0^3)=f(0)+[f(0)]^3 \implies f(0) - f(0) = [f(0)]^3 \implies f(0) = 0
$$This means our function simplifies to:$$
f(t^3) = [f(t)]^3
$$Next let $(x,y)=(t,c)$ where $c$ is some arbitrary constant with respect to $t$:$$
f(t+c^3) = f(t) + [f(c)]^3
$$Differentiate both sides with respect to $t$:$$
f'(t+c^3) = f'(t) \implies f'(c^3) = f'(0) \geq 0
$$Since $c$ is any arbitrary constant, this means that $f'$ is always non-negative and so $f$ is always increasing or constant. So $0<1 \implies f(0)\leq f(1) \implies 0 \leq f(1)$.

Next let $(x,y)=(0,1)$:$$
f(1^3)=f(1) = [f(1)]^3 \implies f(1) = 1 \lor f(1) = 0
$$The fact that $0 \leq f(1)$ rules out $f(1)=-1$.

Next let $(x,y)=(1,1)$:$$
f(1+1^3) = f(1) + [f(1)]^3 \implies f(2) = 1 + 1^3 = 2 \lor f(2) = 0
$$Next let $(x,y)=(2,2)$:$$
f(2+2^3) = f(2) + [f(2)]^3 \implies f(10) = 2 + 2^3 = 10 \lor f(10) = 0
$$

---

It would appear that $f(x)=x$ satisfies both conditions of the provided function.$$
f'(0) = 1 \geq 0 \quad \land\quad f(x+y^3) = x+y^3 = f(x) + [f(y)]^3
$$

It would appear that $f(x)=0$ also satisfies both conditions.$$
f'(0) = 0 \geq 0 \quad \land\quad f(x+y^3) = 0 = 0 + [0]^3
$$

Comment: Very nice, but you can't quite jump from $f(1)=(f(1))^3$ to $f(1)=1$.  $f(1)=0$ and $-1$ are also possible values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was wondering where I would use $f'(0)\geq 0$, and now I know.

Comment: I'd actually like to see how you use that assumption to rule out $f(1)=-1$.  It's not obvious to me!

Comment: Ah, here's a thought:  $f(x+y^3)=f(x)+(f(y))^3\implies f'(x+y^3)=f'(x)\implies f'(y^3)=f'(0)\ge0$ for all $y$, so the Mean Value Theorem rules out $f(1)=-1$, since we already know $f(0)=0$.

Comment: In retrospect, I think $f(x) = 0$ also satisfies the equations.

Comment: you are absolutely correct.  The solution $f(10)=10$ would be unique if the assumption were $f'(0)\gt0$.  But $f'(0)=0$ allows for $f$ to be identically $0$.  I do like your "bootstrapping" from $1$ to $2$ to $10$.